# C# Multithreading Console runtime error

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, console

I have a Console app that uses a parallel.foreach producing a number of working threads that performs some tasks such as

1. reading OS data through SNMP from a number of servers in our intranet and
2. writes these values to a SQL server DB.

When I ran the code within Visual Studio 2010 in either debug- or release mode the program executes without exceptions. When I deploy the program and run it outside VS I get an exception (.NET Runtime Exceptiopn).

Stack Trace:

> Application: ServerMonitorSNMP.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.AggregateException Stack: at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker[[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]](Int32, Int32, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions, System.Action`1,
>
> ...
>
> at ServerMonitoringSNMP.Program.Main(System.String[])

The AggregateException details are:

> System.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
>
> ...
>
> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
>
> ...
>
> (Inner Exception #1) System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
>
> ...
>
> (Inner Exception #2) System.InvalidOperationException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached.
>
> ...
>
> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at ServerMonitoringSNMP.Program.GetStorageValue(Dictionary`2 StorageQuery, Int32 diskOidIndex) in \Program.cs:line 896

Comment: Catch the exception and log it somewhere to see what went wrong?

Answer (score 3):

This is an unhandled [aggregate exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You will need to catch this type of error, loop through its exceptions and log each one to figure out what is going on.

You are probably not breaking on these types of exceptions in your debug routine.

Turn on Break on All Exceptions (Debug, Exceptions) or (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>) and rerun the program.
This will show you the original exception when it was thrown in the first place.

Catch code:

```
catch (AggregateException e)
{
    foreach (var ex in e.InnerExceptions)
    {
       //log here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just tried but right now I don't get any exceptions at all. Seems they appear randomly? I'll try again tomorrow.

Comment: @peer754 Just put your exception handling and logging in place and then you can find it when it comes up.  You might have a race condition if it seems to appear randomly.

Comment: Hi, I finally managed to capture some of the errors, too many rows to fit into this comment so I'll post it as an Answer instead, hope that's ok? 
In this post it seems I have two kinds of unhandled exceptions:

1) Time-out
2) Nullreference

Comment: Just to be more thorough regarding my code:
In my parallel loop, all variables are local to each thread. I do however, have calls to private methods to which I send Dictionary<Oid, AsnType> datatypes as input parameters and from I get int or long as output. All of these are also local.

Comment: @peer754 With regard to you answer, you should probably trim it down. only the lines of `(Inner Exception #1)...` and such will really mean anything to anyone here.  Then you can add it to your original post.

Comment: @peer754 The null reference is a very common one.  you are trying to call a property of an object, but that object is null so the property doesnt exist. `ServerMonitoringSNMP.Program.GetStorageValue(Dictionary StorageQuery, Int32 diskOidIndex) in \\Program.cs:line 896` this is where you are calling that object.  Check values there and put error handling around it.

Comment: @peer754 The timeout, is just that, your thread cant get an answer from the database before it gives up.  You can raise your timeout value to fix this, but its usually indicative of a poor or far too large query.

Answer (score 2):

The attached exception is too abstract. The best approach would be handle the TPL exception and log. Things shall be much clearer when you do so. Then you can updated the post with proper exception.

Eg:

```
      try
        {
            YourSNMPTrapSenderMethod();
        }
       catch (AggregateException ae)
        {
            // This is where you can choose which exceptions to handle. 
            foreach (var ex in ae.InnerExceptions)
            {
               // log your exception. may be in temp directory
            }
        }
```

**Or**

```
        try
        {
            YourSNMPTrapSenderMethod();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            ex.Handle((x) =>
            {
                Log.Write(x);
                return true;
            });
        }


   static void YourSNMPTrapSenderMethod()
    {
        var exceptions = new ConcurrentQueue<Exception>();
        Parallel.ForEach(data, d =>
        {
            try
            {
              //do your operations
            }

            catch (Exception e) { exceptions.Enqueue(e); }
        });


        if (exceptions.Count > 0) throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
```